# replace current_date() from sql with a date in pandas

Tags: python, sql, pandas, replace

I have a column with several queries in a dataframe and I would like to replace wherever the CURRENT_DATE() occurs

```
dict = {'Table Name':'Null', 'Script':'SELECT ID FROM TABLE 1 WHERE CAST(datepartion) BETWEEN '2022-06-01' AND CURRENT_DATE()}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict)

date = '2022-06-29'
date_ = f"CAST('{date}' AS DATE)"
```

if I use

```
df['Column'].replace('CURRENT_DATE()', date_, inplace=True, regex=True)
```

it will return the following as desired with the exception of the parentheses at the end.

```
CAST('2022-06-29' AS DATE)()
```

Any help to how to approach the problem.
Thanks

Comment: Please post sample of your dataframe?

Comment: Ok, I will do that.

Comment: Also sample of your expected output

Comment: I added a minimal example as the data is worked related and due GDPR I can't share it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`()` has special meaning in regex, you actually don't need `regex`

```py
df['Script'] = df['Script'].str.replace('CURRENT_DATE()', date_, regex=False)
```

```
print(df)

  Table Name  \
0       Null

                                                                                   Script
0  SELECT ID FROM TABLE 1 WHERE CAST(datepartion) BETWEEN '2022-06-01' AND CURRENT_DATE()
```

Or escape `()`

```py
df['Script'].replace('CURRENT_DATE\(\)', date_, inplace=True, regex=True)
```

Comment: Thanks @Ynjxsjmh, escaping the () worked well. Much appreciated, removing the regex though did not.